# Redirect back to previous page after completion of bulk action in woocommerce shop order page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently working on implementing a bulk action functionality that sends an email to our delivery drivers when an order is ready for delivery. I've added a 5-second reload to ensure email is sent successfully.

However, after performing the bulk action and waiting for the 5-second delay, the page is not automatically redirecting back to the previous page as expected.

I've provided the relevant code below for your review:

```
 
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'add_bulk_action_order_ready' );
function add_bulk_action_order_ready( $actions ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
        $user_now=$current_user->display_name;
        $role = array_shift($user_roles);
        if ($user_now=='dharmendra yadav' || $user_now=='Mayur Chikane' || $user_now=='kanai mandal' || $role=='administrator' ) {
                 $actions['order_ready'] = __( 'Mark Order Ready', 'textdomain' );
    }
    return $actions;
}
// Handle the custom bulk action
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'handle_bulk_action_order_ready', 30, 3 );
function handle_bulk_action_order_ready( $redirect_to, $action, $order_ids ) {
    if ( $action !== 'order_ready' ) {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
    $order_ids = isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post'] : array();
    if ( empty( $order_ids ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    ?> 

<script>setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 5000); </script> 

<?php 
    
    foreach ( $order_ids as $order_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
        
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Order_Ready', 'Yes' );
        
        
        $status = $order->get_status();
        $meta_data = $order->get_meta_data();
    
        if($status=='driver-assigned' || $status== 'out-for-delivery'){
            foreach ( $meta_data as $meta ) {
                if ( $meta->key === 'lddfw_driverid' ) {
                    $driver_id = $meta->value;
                }
                if ( $meta->key === 'Order_Ready' ) {
                    $order_ready_value = $meta->value;

                    if ( $order_ready_value === 'Yes' ) {
                        // Check if email has already been sent
                        $email_sent = $order->get_meta( 'email_sent', true );

                        if ( $email_sent != 'Yes' ) {
                            // Get driver information
                            $driver = get_userdata( $driver_id );
                            $driver_name = $driver->display_name;
                            $driver_email = $driver->user_email;

                            // Send email to driver
                            $subject = 'Order no. ' . $order_id . ' ready for pickup';
                            $message = 'Hello ' . $driver_name . ',<br><br> Order no. ' . $order_id . ' is now ready for pickup.';
                            $headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );

                            add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'original_mail_bulk_address_email');
                            add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'email_name_bulk_order_ready');

                            if ( wp_mail( $driver_email, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
                                // Update email_sent meta value
                                $order->update_meta_data( 'email_sent', 'Yes' );
                                $order->save();
                                 remove_filter('wp_mail_from', 'original_mail_bulk_address_email');
                                 remove_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'email_name_bulk_order_ready');
                                
                                ?>
                                        <script>
                                            var $previousPageUrl = wp_get_referer();
                                        //var previousPageUrl = document.referrer;
                                        //setTimeout(function(){
                                            //window.location.href = previousPageUrl;
                                        //}, 3000); // Delay in milliseconds
                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                            window.location.href = '<?php echo esc_url( $previousPageUrl ); ?>';
                                        }, 10000);
                                    </script> <?php
                            }  else {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function original_mail_bulk_address_email(){
    $email ='ovenfreshretail01@gmail.com';
    return $email;
}
function email_name_bulk_order_ready(){
    return 'Oven Fresh';
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this problem and ensure that the page successfully redirects to the previous page after the 5-second delay. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**UPDATE**

As per feedback I've added `wp_safe_redirect` instead of JS yet there's no change in the behavior

Here's the updated code:

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'add_bulk_action_order_ready' );
function add_bulk_action_order_ready( $actions ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_now = $current_user->display_name;
    $role = array_shift( $user_roles );
    if ( $user_now == 'dharmendra yadav' || $user_now == 'Mayur Chikane' || $user_now == 'kanai mandal' || $role == 'administrator' ) {
        $actions['order_ready'] = __( 'Mark Order Ready', 'textdomain' );
    }
    return $actions;
}

// Handle the custom bulk action
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'handle_bulk_action_order_ready', 30, 3 );
function handle_bulk_action_order_ready( $redirect_to, $action, $order_ids ) {
    if ( $action !== 'order_ready' ) {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
    $order_ids = isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post'] : array();
    if ( empty( $order_ids ) ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ( $order_ids as $order_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Order_Ready', 'Yes' );

        $status = $order->get_status();
        $meta_data = $order->get_meta_data();

        if ( $status == 'driver-assigned' || $status == 'out-for-delivery' ) {
            foreach ( $meta_data as $meta ) {
                if ( $meta->key === 'lddfw_driverid' ) {
                    $driver_id = $meta->value;
                }
                if ( $meta->key === 'Order_Ready' ) {
                    $order_ready_value = $meta->value;

                    if ( $order_ready_value === 'Yes' ) {
                        // Check if email has already been sent
                        $email_sent = $order->get_meta( 'email_sent', true );

                        if ( $email_sent != 'Yes' ) {
                            // Get driver information
                            $driver = get_userdata( $driver_id );
                            $driver_name = $driver->display_name;
                            $driver_email = $driver->user_email;

                            // Send email to driver
                            $subject = 'Order no. ' . $order_id . ' ready for pickup';
                            $message = 'Hello ' . $driver_name . ',<br><br> Order no. ' . $order_id . ' is now ready for pickup.';
                            $headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );

                            add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'original_mail_bulk_address_email' );
                            add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'email_name_bulk_order_ready' );

                            if ( wp_mail( $driver_email, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
                                // Update email_sent meta value
                                $order->update_meta_data( 'email_sent', 'Yes' );
                                $order->save();
                                remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'original_mail_bulk_address_email' );
                                remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'email_name_bulk_order_ready' );

                                $previousPageUrl = wp_get_referer();
                                wp_safe_redirect( $previousPageUrl );
                                exit;
                            } else {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function original_mail_bulk_address_email() {
    $email = 'ovenfreshretail01@gmail.com';
    return $email;
}

function email_name_bulk_order_ready() {
    return 'Oven Fresh';
}
```

Comment: use wp_safe_redirect() instead ?

Comment: Hey @Snuffy can you show me how can I implement this in my code.?

Comment: replace js redirect with wp_safe_redirect and add the url. Also wp_get_referer will return false if its same url https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_referer/

Comment: @Snuffy I've added this line 
 `$previousPageUrl = wp_get_referer();
                                wp_safe_redirect( $previousPageUrl );
  exit;
`

yet there are no changes, the behavior is still the same.

Comment: what you have in $previousPageUrl is it the url you want to redirect ?

Comment: I don't want to redirect to a specific URL, I just want it to redirect to the whatever the previous URL was  that's it.

Comment: As i said if wp_get_referer() is holding the same url will return false so there is nothing to redirect with js or wp_safe_redirect. So check what you get from $previousPageUrl .